# 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm building an app and developed a Today Extension for it a month or two ago. Randomly, while running it maybe the 10th time in in iOS 11 Beta, I got an error for the first time and now the entire app will not build.

> /Users/Documents/AppName/Pods/CarbonKit/CarbonKit/CarbonTabSwipeNavigation.m:622:27:
>   'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App
>   Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate
>   instead.

The error appears in a Pod, but it's in a file that in written in Obj-C, not Swift, so it is hard to understand.

These are the lines the error appears on:

```
  // Some projects use GTM_BACKGROUND_TASK_FETCHING to avoid compile-time references
  // to UIApplication.
#if GTM_BACKGROUND_TASK_FETCHING
  return (id<GTMUIApplicationProtocol>) [UIApplication sharedApplication]; <- error
#else
  return nil;
#endif
```

Could anyone give advice on how to solve this error? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: @rmaddy why did you get rid of my swift tag? i put it there because my app is written in swift, so it is pertinent to this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at what google has to say on this subject?  I stopped skimming after the second page of results.

Comment: @rmaddy i did mention that its written in swift. "...written in Obj-C, not Swift, so it is hard to understand."

Comment: @danh yeah i tried. all related to other pods, not carbon kit. i found something abt alamofire but the answer was completely different than my case. thanks though

Comment: If you look at the [description for the swift tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) it says "Use the tag only for questions about language features, *or requiring code in Swift.*" As such there is no reason to remove the tag.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.
Go to your target build settings and find `Require Only AppExtension-Safe API` and set the value to `No`. 
This will silence this error.

Answer (score 3):

As the error clearly states, the following API is not available for use in Today Extensions:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication]
```

Please read the Apple provided [documentation on App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2):

> ### Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions
>
> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is ineligible to participate in certain activities. An app extension cannot:
>
> - Access a `sharedApplication` object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object
>
> *- Apple, App Extension Programming Guide*

Make sure that *CarbonKit* (or, really, anything that uses these APIs) is **not included** in your Today App Extension **target**. Xcode should have automatically warned you about this as soon as it was included in your extension target (although it is possible to silence these warnings temporarily).

Comment: thanks so much for answering! carbonkit is not included in the section of my podfile for the today extension. thats why its so weird! any clue?

Comment: These files are not included in the "Target Membership" section of your Utilities Inspector, or in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase, or the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase?

Comment: no not at all. its weird bc it shows up in two places. once in a carbonkit file, which *is not* in the target membership of the podfile for the Today Extension, and once again in a GTMSessionFetcher file, which Firebase uses and Firebase *is* included in the target membership of the podfile for the Today Extension. Still very confused